# Do I need to find user in database if I include everything into jwt payload?

Tags: express, mongoose, jwt, passport.js, passport-jwt

I use JSON Web Tokens and passport-jwt package.

```
const payload = {
     id: this.id,
     name: this.name,
     email: this.email,
     avatar: this.avatar,
     isAdmin: this.isAdmin
};

JWT.sign( payload, keys.secretOrKey, {
      algorithm: 'HS256',
      expiresIn: this.expiresIn,
      jwtid: await this.getJwtId()
});
```

and inside middleware

```
module.exports = ( passport ) => {
    passport.use( 
        new JwtStrategy( options, async ( jwt_payload, done ) => {  
            User.findById( jwt_payload.id ).then( ( user ) => {
                if ( user ) { 
                    return done( null, user );
                } else {
                    return done( null, false );
                }
            });
        })
    );
};
```

Can I skip **User.findById** and use only **jwt_payload**?

Something like that:

```
module.exports = ( passport ) => {
    passport.use( 
        new JwtStrategy( options, ( jwt_payload, done ) => {    
            return done( null, jwt_payload );
        })
    );
};
```

Comment: I'd say : you decide. Both solution work of course. In my opinion I would query database to make sure that data contained by your Jwt are "up to date" and update it... But if you do that to verify your token's validity (signature, expiration...), then you certainly don't need to query database :)

Comment: You're right. Database query would be better approach if I want to make sure that data are up to date. Thanks! :)